# How to animate a message that appears on bottom?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt5.4

I'm showing a message on the bottom:

*Msg.qml*

```
import QtQuick 2.4

Item {
    property alias text: mf.text
    anchors.fill: parent
    antialiasing: false
    opacity: 0.9
    z: 100

    MsgForm {
        id: mf
        width: parent.width
        y: parent.height - height - 5
    }
}
```

*MsgForm.ui.qml*

```
import QtQuick 2.4

Item {
    property alias text: msg.text

    width: 200

    id: message
    height: msg.height+10

    Rectangle {
        id: rectangle
        color: "#fb9191"
        anchors.fill: parent
        border.color: "#fd6666"
        border.width: 2

        Text {
            id: msg
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.topMargin: 2
            textFormat: Text.PlainText
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.rightMargin: 4
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.leftMargin: 4
            wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
            clip: false
            font.bold: true
            font.pointSize: 12
            font.family: "Tahoma"
        }
    }
}
```

How can I animate the form to appear from the bottom smoothly?
After the animation, if the window resizes, the message must stay always on the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone. In the end I've solved the issue by following advices received in the [qtcentre forum](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/63230-How-animate-a-message-that-appears-on-bottom?highlight=).

The desired effect can be achieved easily by defining a local numerical property that is use to bind to either an `anchors.XXXXmargin` or the `y` property expression.

Following this approach a possible solution is the following:

```
MsgForm {
    property bool showing: false
    property int position: showing ? height : 0
    width: parent.width
    y: parent.height - position
    Behavior on position {
        NumberAnimation {duration: 500}
    }   
}
```

Comment: Mark it as answer, I tested all other solutions before this one, the only working for me!

Answer (score 1):

You can make an animation on the `opacity` change:

### Msg.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.4

Item {
    property alias text: mf.text
    anchors.fill: parent
    antialiasing: false
    opacity: 0.9
    z: 100
    MouseArea{
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: mf.opacity = !mf.opacity
    }
    MsgForm {
        id: mf
        //y: parent.height - height - 5
        opacity:0
        Behavior on opacity {
            NumberAnimation{
                duration:600
            }
        }
        width: parent.width
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom 
    }
}
```

or any other `NumberAnimation`. I recommand you to create `State`s, within it do some propertyChanges, and on some actions, example button clicked change states.
example in your MsgForm.ui.qml add:

```
MouseArea{
    anchors.fill: parent
    onClicked: mf.state= "show"
}
```

and in the action, example:
in my mouseArea I change the state of mf

```
MouseArea{
    anchors.fill: parent
    onClicked: mf.state= "show"
}
```

If you want an Animation on the `y` try this:

### MsgForm.ui.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.4

Item {
    id: message
    property alias text: msg.text
    width: parent.width
    height: msg.height+10

    Rectangle {
        id: rectangle
        color: "#fb9191"
        anchors.fill: parent
        border.color: "#fd6666"
        border.width: 2

        Text {
            id: msg
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.topMargin: 2
            textFormat: Text.PlainText
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.rightMargin: 4
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.leftMargin: 4
            wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
            clip: false
            font.bold: true
            font.pointSize: 12
            font.family: "Tahoma"
        }
    }
    Behavior on y {
        NumberAnimation{
            duration:300
        }
    }
    states: [
        State {
            name: "show"
            PropertyChanges {
                target: message
                y: parent.height - height
            }
        },
        State {
            name: "hide"
            PropertyChanges {
                target: message
                y: parent.height + height + 5
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

### Msg.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.4

Rectangle {
    property alias text: mf.text
    width:800
    height: 480
    antialiasing: false
    opacity: 0.9
    z: 100
    MouseArea{
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked:  mf.state= "show"
    }
    MsgForm {
        id: mf
        //y: parent.height - height - 5
        y: parent.height +height + 5
        width: parent.width
    }
}
```

Comment: The same that occurs with the Jairo response. Appears on the final place an goes down.

Comment: Can you post your code cause I dont have this behavior

Comment: This solution works for me. Modifying the onClicked statement as `onClicked:  mf.state = mf.state === "show" ? "hide" : "show"` provides reverse animation.

Answer (score 1):

You can play with `anchors.bottomMargin` property to raise the message item from the bottom.

```
import QtQuick 2.4

Item {
    property alias text: mf.text
    anchors.fill: parent
    antialiasing: false
    opacity: 0.9
    z: 100

    MsgForm {
        id: mf
        property bool showing: false

        width: parent.width
        anchors{
            bottom: parent.bottom
            bottomMargin: mf.showing ? 0 : -mf.height
            Behavior on bottomMargin{
                NumberAnimation{  }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. The message appears on the final place and goes bottom. It seems that QML initializes boottomMargin to 0, and when initializes the bottomMargin to -mf.height, then animates.